# How to handle ParseErrors in Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

So I have an application that collects the header and footer sections of an HTML document and inserts them into a preexisting web page. Both sections are already wrapped in div tags so the content within the boxes shouldn't have html/body tags.

That being said, I'd like to check for tags that aren't closed and programmatically close them. I'm very new to Html Agility Pack and I'm not sure how to accomplish what I want. Here is the code that I have been able to infer based upon Google searches.

```
    private bool RepairHtml(string htmlText)
    {
        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlText);
        var parseErrors = htmlDoc.ParseErrors;

        if (parseErrors != null)
        {
           foreach (var htmlParseError in parseErrors)
           {
              switch (htmlParseError.Code)
              {
                 case: HtmlParseErrorCode.TagNotClosed:
                    // Not sure what to do here
                    break;
              }
           }
        }
     }
```

How do I select the tag that generated an error and close it?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.OptionFixNestedTags = true;` to fix them automatically.

You can check [here](https://github.com/jstedfast/HtmlAgilityPack/blob/master/HtmlAgilityPack/HtmlParseErrorCode.cs) for array list of errors.

You can use htmlParseError.Line to see what is causing error. Hope that helps

Comment: Whoever compiled the HtmlAgilityPack version 1.4.1.0 included a reference to the System.Xml.XPath version 2.0.5.0 as I'm getting an error about it (Unable to load file or assembly 'System.Xml.XPath, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<hash#>'). I have version 5.0.5.0 of the System.Xml.XPath library. This is the pre-compiled version from the website. I don't necessarily have time to get the source code, put it into a project, and get it to compile. Is this the only way to fix this error?

Comment: I'll try to get a library up and running after work.

Comment: I was finally able to get the library working. Thank you @Kuzgun for your answer!